# *ngFor causing template error

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I'm getting this error:

```
Template parse errors:↵Parser Error: Conditional expression result?categories requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression [ngFor let category of result?categories] in ResultAttributesComponent@32:17
```

from this template:

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <div id="categories">
            <div *ngFor="let category of result?categories">
               <div class="category1">

               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

here is the result object:

```
{
        id: 15,
        name: 'sugar free dark chocolate salted caramel',
        brand: "alpro",
        description: "Delicious sugar free dark chocolate in everyones favourite flavour, salted caramel.",
        image: "result-images/sugar_free_dark_chocolate_salted_caramel.png",
        rating: 9.2,
        nearbyShops:[],
        categories: ["dessert", "Baking"],
        averagePrice: 4.32,
        amount: "400g",
        reviews: [{
            id: 11,
            description: 'It was pretty amazing!',
            rating: 9.1,
            user: {
                id: 1,
                userName: "BeniaminoBaggins",
            },
            comments: [{
                id: 1,
                description: "great review!",
                user: {
                    id: 2,
                    userName: "IrishNimue"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `.` in your loop expression:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of result?.categories">
```